# How to get a product price from different sites

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a product price details from  different sites in the internet. User will enter search criteria such as 'Mobile phone'.When user type on mobile phone the site should display all links of mobile phone selling sites with different price. Can we do it in php?

Comment: And what did you tried?

Comment: Yes, you need to make a web crawler.

Comment: `Can we do it in php?` yes!, the question `Can YOU do it in php?` I don't know

Comment: i have used the php script in http://webdevwonders.com/simple-php-crawler-example/. but i have changed both $content and 
$content_tag  variable but the file doesn't contain any links.

Comment: i did the changes
$content = "nokia"; and $content_tag = "p"; but didn't get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to use a HTML DOM scraper...

Look into the [Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for PHP, you will need to (for each site) -

Grab the page you want to scrape:

```
$html = file_get_dom('http://www.somephonesite.com/iphone5.html');
```

Find the element on it and save it:

```
$prices['somephonesite'] = $html->find('span[id=price]')->plaintext;
```

Obviously you will need to define a function per site as not all sites will use a span or the same `price` ID etc, then you'll put all the sites in your database along with the function name and call it on a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Can we get all mobile sites links order by price to save it on database. Do we use cron task for this? Can we do it by using web crawler? i did the changes $content = "nokia"; and $content_tag = "p"; but didn't get any result.

Comment: @user1440444 You would have to get a list of sites somewhere, and then you would have to work out how to submit searches to them and follow correct results. This is *not* a simple task, it's a long and complicated process which will be different for every site you use.

Comment: Is there api for getting all mobile site urls?

Comment: @user1440444 I very much doubt it.